# Deploy portal-ext liferay error

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to deploy a portal ext plugin, that only overrides the **loginpostaction** to fix the **nullpointerexception** bug when trying to enable live.users tracker.

http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-24839

When I deploy in local environment this works ok, but when I deploy it on a production server, nothing happens. The log shows that the deploy is okay, but the portal continues to use the old class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but there may be another ext overriding the same class. Also, some exted classes won't be used until you restart the webapp server for the first time since deploying ext.

Comment: another guess, have you restarted the portal (ext plugin requires portal restart).

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming that you have written **another** EXT plugin to fix some `NullPointerException` existing in your **previous** plugin.

Its important to remember that once an EXT plugin has been deployed, some of its files are copied inside the Liferay installation, so the only way to remove its changes is to redeploy an unmodified Liferay application again.

Also, there is a tip at the end of this [link](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/creating-an-ext-plugin)

"After creating an Ext plugin, remove all of the files added by default that are not necessary for the extension. This is important because Liferay keeps track of the files deployed by each Ext plugin and it won't allow deploying two Ext plugins if they override the same file to avoid collisions. By removing any files not really necessary from an ext plugin it will be easier to use along with other Ext plugins."

These concepts might be helpful in finding your problem.